# ggplot2() plotting one variable against itself by factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggplot to create a geom_point with two lines, typically these two lines are from two different variables within a dataframe e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=var1,y=var2),data = df) + geom_point()
```

However in this case I have one variable which is stacked vertically (representative of a replicate 1 and 2) and in another column there is a score (again from two replicates):

```
data.frame(fac=c(rep("trial1",10),rep("trial2",10)),score=rnorm(20,2,1))
```

What I want to do is a simple ggplot or line graph of trial 1 in y axis and trial 2 on x axis. In the base plot function this is simple to do as all it needs is for the data to be split into two different data frames. However in ggplot I always use the same data frame and from what I know I can't use two separate data frames for the call. So how do I do this?

I was guessing there was some work around using group_by to arrange data.frame prior to plotting but I wasn't sure how to implement it. I hope this is sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using tidyverse functions, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
dd %>% 
  group_by(fac) %>% 
  mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
  spread(fac, score) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(trial2, trial1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you just clarify the mutate(id=1:n())? Is this essentially creating an index for length of each factor? If so does it matter that they aren't in sequential order?

Comment: Well you need some way to match up a trial 1 value to a trial 2 values. I had assumed you wanted them matched up in the order that they appear. This just indexes them within the groups so they can be matched up.

Comment: Ok I'll try to sort by a third column which is essentially a unique identifier (id) then see what happens. Will report back.

Comment: If you already have an ID, then you can just use that. No need to create a fake one.

Comment: OK so when I do it it creates two columns but inserts NAs alternating between rows meaning that it won't plot properly. Essentially each id is staggered by one row.

Comment: Does each ID have both a trial1 and trail2 value? Hard to say what's going on without a reproducible example.

Comment: Each ID has both a trial 1 value and trial 2 value. I'm sorry data is quite complex. If I can't sort it I'll try and get a more reproducible example made

Comment: I've managed to get it to work if I only select() the columns I'm interested in, if I don't it introduces NAs between them. Must be something to do with rows not being unique.

Answer (score 2):

I would still use one data.frame, but reshaped (you can use `dcast` from `reshape2` package). For example:

```
# use `nrow(df) / 2` to split data in half
df2 <- reshape2::dcast(df, seq_len(nrow(df) / 2) ~ fac, value.var = "score")
```

And then simply plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(trial2, trial1)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went for first option but looks good.